# I'm in a perpetual state of loading

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This webpage is in a perpetual state of loading and I don't know why. It's almost as if it's awaiting the data. I tested the backend and the user exists and should be being sent but it's just waiting. I also tried isolating the the code so that it's just the bare minimum needed and there's still the perpetual loading. The This is what it looks like: [Edit user Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ejd.png)  Below is the code:

UserEditScreens.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import { getError } from "../utils";
import { Store } from "./Store";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.value) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    case "FETCH_FAIL":
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case "UPDATE_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loadingUpdate: true };
    case "UPDATE_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, loadingUpdate: false };
    case "UPDATE_FAIL":
      return { ...state, loadingUpdate: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function UserEditScreen() {
  const [{ loading, error, loadingUpdate }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    error: "",
  });
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  const params = useParams();
  const { id: userId } = params;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_REQUEST" });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${userId}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAIL", payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [userInfo, userId]);
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_REQUEST" });
      await axios.put(
        `/api/users/${userId}`,
        { _id: userId, firstName, lastName, email, isAdmin },
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` } }
      );
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SUCCESS" });
      toast.success("User updated successfully");
      navigate("/admin/users");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(getError(error));
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FAIL" });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Helmet>Edit User #{userId}</Helmet>
      <h1>Edit User #{userId}</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="firstName">
            <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={firstName}
              type="name"
              onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={lastName}
              type="name"
              onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="lastName">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={email}
              type="email"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Check
            className="mb-3"
            type="checkbox"
            id="isAdmin"
            label="isAdmin"
            checked={isAdmin}
            onChange={(e) => setIsAdmin(e.target.checked)}
          ></Form.Check>

          <div>
            <Button disabled={loadingUpdate} type="submit">
              Update
            </Button>
            {loadingUpdate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

UserRoutes.js

```
import express from "express";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { generateToken, isAuth } from "../utils.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get(
  "/",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.send(users);
  })
);
userRouter.get(
  "/:id",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (user) {
      console.log(user);
      res.send(user);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not Found" });
    }
  })
);
userRouter.put(
  "/:id",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    if (user) {
      const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
      user.firstName = req.body.firstName || user.firstName;
      user.lastName = req.body.lastName || user.lastName;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
      user.isAdmin = Boolean(req.body.isAdmin);
      const updatedUser = await user.save();
      res.send({ message: "User Updated", user: updatedUser });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User Not Found" });
    }
  })
);

userRouter.post(
  "/signin",
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
        res.send({
          _id: user._id,
          name: user.firstName,
          email: user.email,
          token: generateToken(user),
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
  })
);

userRouter.post(
  "/signup",
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.firstName,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password),
    });
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.send({
      _id: user._id,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user),
    });
  })
);

userRouter.put(
  "/profile",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (user) {
      user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
      user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
      if (req.body.password) {
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8);
      }
      const updatedUser = await user.save();
      res.send({
        _id: updatedUser._id,
        name: updatedUser.name,
        email: updatedUser.email,
        isAdmin: updatedUser.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(updatedUser),
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" });
    }
  })
);
export default userRouter;
```

Comment: So where's the issue exactly, your frontend or your backend?

Comment: I guess there would be 2 possible causes for the loading. The first is the machine calculate without stop by loop and the second is the front-end page is waiting for response from the server. As it is networking between front and back, I guess the cause is never ending waiting for response.

Comment: It could also be an issue in `isAuth`, but we won't know without more information.

Comment: By the way, at `put` request `/:id` in `UserRouter.js`, `user` is used before it's defined?

Comment: @robertklep the isAuth function works with the other paths `export const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authorization) {
    const token = authorization.slice(7, authorization.length);
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decode) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).send({ message: "Invalid Token" });
      } else {
        req.user = decode;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: "No Token" });
  }
};`

Comment: Oh and @robertklep the issue seems to be at the frontend because the backend is sending a user.